# What is the use of Mule Agent?

Tags: mule

could someone please help me what is the purpose of Mule Agent, how it works and what are the scenarios where we can use mule agent?

Thanks,
Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

Mule agent is used to monitor and control Mule servers and as well as using Mule agent API you can

1) Controlling applications, domains and services

2) List, deploy, undeploy or redeploy domains

3) List, deploy, undeploy, get status of, start or stop applications

4) Publishing Mule metrics to external monitoring systems

For more details read the mule documentation

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-agent/v/1.1.1/